# Create SOAP web server with Java and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I would like to create simple Java SOAP web service that should run on Tomcat 10. I'm using Eclipse and Maven for this purpose. I'm creating new Maven project and was stuck with Archetype selection. Which Archetype I should use?

Can I create project without selecting `archetype`? What basic section should exist in my `pom.xml`?

Comment: Did you try my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `maven-archetype-webapp`.

Your pom will need some/all of the following to build a SOAP WS as a warfile to run in Tomcat.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyServiceWS</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>MyServiceWS</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.jws/jakarta.jws-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.soap/jakarta.xml.soap-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>MyServiceWS</finalName>
    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
    <!-- main -->
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <!-- test -->
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*.properties</include>
          <include>*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            <warSourceExcludes>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</warSourceExcludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```